# Should cassette "wiggle"

Tags: maintenance, repair, hub, cassette, freewheel

Recently My freehub broke and so I removed the cassette to replace the freehub and noticed, whilst off the bike, 4 of the remaining bolted together 8 sprockets wiggled (4 wiggled together but separately from the other 4). (10 speed shimano hg62-10). I also noticed some scratch marks on the freehub body (see pic) and wondered if this had anything to do with it. Does my cassette need replacing, or is this OK?

[image: freehub body]

Comment: Which direction does it wiggle in?

Comment: in the direction of the chain. so rotatates slightly. im talking approx 2-3mm of rotational movement

Comment: The scratch marks are also normal. If burrs, hit them lightly with a file. In extreme cases, these can become gouges leading to a bit of movement in the cassette in which case you should consider replacing.

Comment: To add to this I've also seen a cassette wobble where the cause was a loose freehub body.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're saying that, off the body, the sprockets move slightly relative to each other, that's not a problem.  The sprockets are only just "tacked" together so that they remain in the right order and orientation while off the body.  The body provides the strength to hold them.

If, on the other hand, you notice that the sprockets slide up and down the body after installation, or if they seem to wobble as they turn, that suggests that they were installed incorrectly relative to the notches or that a spacer is missing.

Comment: I would go with the missing spacer or a cross-threaded lockring.

Comment: http://sheldonbrown.com/k7.html#hyperdrivec

Comment: Yes. This is off the body. I will replace it and see what happens then, Thanks.